# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list is appearing on line 1 (<!DOCTYPE html>)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a sample website but I keep running into this syntax error. What I am trying to do is play a music video when the track is clicked on by the user. The src of the iframe should change based on the track clicked. I think the error is being triggered because something is wrong with my setVideo function.

Here is the following HTML..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <html lang="en">  
    <head>
        <title>Kush Gang Music</title>
        <meta charset= "utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="kushgang.css">
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="cd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav>
        <img src="images/kushgang.jpg" height="80px" width="150px">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=index.html>Home</a></li>
            <li class="bg"><a href=social.html>Social</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Alize</a></li>
                            <li><a>Doe</a></li>
                            <li><a>Leathal</a></li>
                            <li><a>J. Noel</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="grid">
                <div id="m_wrapper" class="row">

                    <div id="enlarge" class="col-10">
                        <iframe id="iframe" width="1005px" height="354px"></iframe><br /><br />
                        <div id="trackList" class="col-10"></div><br/>
                    </div><br/>
                    <canvas id="canvas1" class="canvas">
                        Your browser does not support Canvas HTML!!
                    </canvas>
                    <div id="slide">
                    <div id="teaser-wrap" class="col-6 s" onclick="setList(cc_cd)">
                        <div class="teaser">
                            <img src="images/ccwaterbound.jpg" alt="CC WaterBound Image">
                            <p>Released: 1996</p>
                            <p>Artist: Critical Condition</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="teaser-wrap" class="col-6 s" onclick="setList(jl_cd)">
                        <div class="teaser">
                            <img src="images/lethal.jfif" alt="CC WaterBound Image">
                            <p>Released: 2015</p>
                            <p>Artist: Lethal</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="teaser-wrap" class="col-6 s" onclick="setList(role_cd)">
                        <div class="teaser">
                            <img src="images/rolee.jfif" alt="CC WaterBound Image">
                            <p>Released: Variety</p>
                            <p>Artist: Ro-Lee</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="teaser-wrap" class="col-6 s" onclick="setList(ali_cd)">
                        <div class="teaser">
                            <img src="images/ali.jfif" alt="CC WaterBound Image">
                            <p>Released: Variety</p>
                            <p>Artist: Alize</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="teaser-wrap" class="col-6 s">
                        <div class="teaser">
                            <img src="images/ccwaterbound.jpg" alt="CC WaterBound Image">
                            <p>Released: 2000</p>
                            <p>Genre: Rap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="teaser-wrap" class="col-6 s">
                        <div class="teaser">
                            <img src="images/ccwaterbound.jpg" alt="CC WaterBound Image">
                            <p>Released: 2000</p>
                            <p>Genre: Rap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="teaser-wrap" class="col-6 s">
                        <div class="teaser">
                            <img src="images/ccwaterbound.jpg" alt="CC WaterBound Image">
                            <p>Released: 2000</p>
                            <p>Genre: Rap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="teaser-wrap" class="col-6 s">
                        <div class="teaser">
                            <img src="images/ccwaterbound.jpg" alt="CC WaterBound Image">
                            <p>Released: 2000</p>
                            <p>Genre: Rap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="teaser-wrap" class="col-6 s">
                        <div class="teaser">
                            <img src="images/ccwaterbound.jpg" alt="CC WaterBound Image">
                            <p>Released: 2000</p>
                            <p>Genre: Rap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="teaser-wrap" class="col-6 s">
                        <div class="teaser">
                            <img src="images/ccwaterbound.jpg" alt="CC WaterBound Image">
                            <p>Released: 2000</p>
                            <p>Genre: Rap</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.s').click(function() {
                    $('#slide').animate({'margin-top':'20px'},300);
                    $('#canvas1').animate({'margin-top':'238px'},300);
                    if($('#trackList').css('display')=='none'){

                        $('#trackList').fadeIn();
                    }else{
                        $('#trackList ul').fadeOut().fadeIn();
                    }   
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
    <footer>
    Website created by Trevor Hollins
    </footer>
</html>
```

Here is the following javaScript..

```
var cc_cd = {

    name: "CC Waterbound",
    date: "Summer 1995",
    t1name: "Intro",
    t1url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Rsh5oQ6JCTI",
    t1length: "0:40",
    t2name: "Bout 2 Go Down",
    t2url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/XgJ6DdIaXd0",
    t2length: "4:44",
    t3name: "Dope and money",
    t3url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/cruY77l99_M",
    t3length: "3:51",
    t4name: "Looking Down the Barrel",
    t4url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/jmLgcnUlgfk",
    t4length: "4:33",
    t5name: "Playa Hatas",
    t5url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZY8eCUuuqJY",
    t5length: "5:18",
    t6name: "4 Real Nigga Possie",
    t6url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/A-syQCa3iN0",
    t6length: "6:14",
    t7name: "CC Waaterbound",
    t7url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/eIAOcKg8xfk",
    t7length: "5:25",
    t8name: "Creepin",
    t9url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/MpBB7rnaw_Q",
    t9length: "3:56",
    t10name: "Hood Cord",
    t10url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/PNMiP67NhcM",
    t10length: "4:11",
    t11name: "All This Dick",
    t11url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/a5zWyURBIjE",
    t11length: "5:25",
    array: function(){
        var array = [this.t1name,this.t1length,this.t1url,this.t2name,this.t2length,this.t2url,this.t3name,this.t3length,this.t3url,this.t4name,this.t4length,this.t4url,this.t5name,this.t5length,this.t5url,this.t6name,this.t6length,this.t6url,this.t7name,this.t7length,this.t7url,this.t8name,this.t8length,this.t8url,this.t9name,this.t9length,this.t9url,this.t10name,this.t10length,this.t10url,this.t11name,this.t11length,this.t11url];
        return array;

    }
}
var jl_cd = {
    name: "Jay Leathal",
    date: "June 2015",
    t1name: "Enemies",
    t1url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/p89TXxEYndg",
    t1length: "2:12",
    t2name: "COCO",
    t2url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/uE9BFDiUej4",
    t2length: "3:55",
    t3name: "Dope and money",
    t3url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/cruY77l99_M",
    t3length: "3:51",
    t4name: "Yeet!!",
    t4url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/bFGG9SJ0LKs",
    t4length: "6:19",

    array: function(){
        var array = [this.t1name,this.t1length,this.t1url,this.t2name,this.t2length,this.t2url,this.t3name,this.t3length,this.t3url,this.t4name,this.t4length,this.t4url];
        return array;

    }
}
var role_cd = {
    name: "Ro Lee",
    date: "2006-2016",
    t1name: "Waterbound Get Ready",
    t1url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/73biX3T7k08",
    t1length: "2:12",
    t2name: "Hello World",
    t2url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/nC_BJxXxqK8",
    t2length: "2:22",
    t3name: "Say You Will Flow",
    t3url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/sSMCZJF8160",
    t3length: "1:51",
    t4name: "Fed Up/End of Time",
    t4url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/RVmDUoQyva0",
    t4length: "3:20",

    array: function(){
        var array = [this.t1name,this.t1length,this.t1url,this.t2name,this.t2length,this.t2url,this.t3name,this.t3length,this.t3url,this.t4name,this.t4length,this.t4url];
        return array;

    }
}
var ali_cd = {
    name: "Alize",
    date: "2004-2016",
    t1name: "Until The End",
    t1url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/awXYuOUplj0",
    t1length: "3:42",
    t2name: "Ice Cream Girl",
    t2url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/FSXxTDCt6Fs",
    t2length: "5:02",
    t3name: "Imma Gorilla",
    t3url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/SREeoX4j29Q",
    t3length: "4:01",
    t4name: "Purple Color Crazy",
    t4url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vp5OILqkCu4",
    t4length: "4:30",
    t5name: "For My Gangstas",
    t5url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/nTV0U_TMNng",
    t5length: "3:48",
    t6name: "I'm a Waterboy",
    t6url:  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JKG5cFAk7gk",
    t6length:   "4:04",
    t7name: "Murda 4 Fun",
    t7url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/2aWpA4k0xKo",
    t7length: "5:41",

    array: function(){
        var array = [this.t1name,this.t1length,this.t1url,this.t2name,this.t2length,this.t2url,this.t3name,this.t3length,this.t3url,this.t4name,this.t4length,this.t4url,this.t5name,this.t5length,this.t5url,this.t6name,this.t6length,this.t6url,this.t7name,this.t7length,this.t7url];
        return array;

    }
}

//Fix function not working properly
function setList(a) {
    alert(a.array().length);
    var trackList= document.getElementById('trackList');
    var li ="";
//for does not need a semicolon at the end also dont forget to declare the variable i.
    for(var i=0; i<a.array().length-1;i=i+3){

        li+="<li onclick='setVideo("+a.array()[i+2]+")'>"+a.array()[i]+"<br/><span>"+a.array()[i+1]+"</span></li>";

    }
    document.getElementById('iframe').src=a.t1url;
    setTimeout(function(){
        trackList.innerHTML = "<div id='t1ul_container'><ul id='t1ul'>"+li+"</ul></div>";
    },0500);


}
function setVideo(a){
    document.getElementById('iframe').src=a;

}

function draw(){

    var canvas= document.getElementById('canvas1');
    var ctx= canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle='#FFFF99';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,800,220);

    ctx.fillStyle="#996633";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(54,86,50,0,Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.fillStyle="#FFFF99";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(67,86,45,0,Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.fillStyle="#996633";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(250,86,50,0,Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.fillStyle="#FFFF99";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(240,86,45,0,Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.strokeStyle="grey";
    ctx.font="50px Arial";
    ctx.lineWidth=2;
    ctx.shadowColor="purple";
    ctx.shadowOffsetX= 10;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY= -5;
    ctx.shadowBlur= 12;
    ctx.strokeText("Kush Gang",32,96);
    ctx.shadowColor="brown";
    ctx.shadowOffsetY=22;
    ctx.shadowBlur= 30;
    ctx.strokeText("Music",85,134);



/*  ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.font="55px Arial";
    ctx.shadowOffsetX=0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY=0;
    ctx.shadowBlur=0;
    ctx.fillText("Alize",35,108);*/

}

window.onload= draw;
```

Comment: Maybe I should have just included the functions but I was unsure where the error could be. Sorry

Comment: I tried to reproduce... But not getting this error. All I get is 5 missing images (which is normal).

Comment: None of the code you've posted has a missing `)` - the only thing missing in your javascript is four `;` - however, javascript can handle that omission without showing an error ... something else is the source of the error

Comment: Can it be the browser? I opened it up in Opera.. And are you able to change the videos successfully?

Comment: When I click on the images alts (CC WaterBound Image) I get this error `setList is not defined`... And I now see you also had spotted this because of the comment `Fix function not working properly`.

Comment: Sorry dude... Forget my last message. The error was my fault. The video loads. Your code is ok here.

Comment: I just dowloaded and installed Opera (for Windows) to test it... To be forgiven for my false error clue. Result: Your code works fine on Opera too.